# Is it necessary to optimize join in hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hive

What is the most optimal way to query in Hive (Datalake, based on hdfs)?
Establishing filters in the tables prior to join them,

```
select* from
(select code from table_1 where type="a") a 
inner join 
(select code from table_2
where type="a") b 
on a.code=b.code
```

Or this way? In `where` condition.

```
Select *
From table_1 inner join table_2 on table_1.codigo=table_2.codigo
Where table_1.type="a" and
Table_2.type="a".
```

Perhaps the most obvious and quickest answer is the first way. But I think that with HDFS the environment is optimized in such a way that it reads the "where" first and then the "join", I mean, HDFS brings an internal code optimization.

Comment: FWIW, in most mainstream relational database systems it wouldn't matter. They're smart enough to optimize both out just as efficiently, usually. I'd be surprised if that wasn't also the case in a system that's supposedly meant to deal with large amounts of data.

Comment: @J.D. I understand, is there documentation for what you're telling me? I would like to read about that

Comment: Probably, but I don't work with Hadoop, so unfortunately I don't have it handy. I'm just going by common sense from past experiences.

Comment: One thing you can do to compare performance between two queries is to compare their execution plans. You can get this with the [`EXPLAIN`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=27362037#content/view/27362037) keyword. Feel free to add them to your question if you want further assistance.